# Practices to undertake while designing interfaces that ask for sensitive information

Tags: confirmation, shopping-cart

Are there color codes or design practices that one should consider while designing interfaces that ask for sensitive information like credit card details or ATM pins?

I have seen several different websites which scream fraud. This probably is because of the way they are designed. Others I have seen look pretty trustworthy to give sensitive details. What are the ways to gain users' confidence? Even a link to some article would help.

Comment: [PCI-DSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI-DSS).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question!

[Stanford Guidelines for Web Credibility](http://credibility.stanford.edu/guidelines/#chi99) should help you. 
[Tips to increase your site's reputation](http://www.mywot.com/en/trustseal/tips) are good, too.
Also it could be interesting for you to touch [Persuasive Design](http://bjfogg.com/fbm_files/page4_1.pdf).

**UPDATE**

There are several factors which influence site credibility and hence people more likely provide sensitive information.

1. Modern and consistent visual appearance
2. Smooth and understandable interaction
3. Personality – show real person/organisation behind the site, provide not only email, but 
   physical address, phone numbers and other contact and personal info
4. Social recognition – includes real users' feedback, list of clients, badges from authoritative organizations and other verifying stuff
5. [Some weapons from persuasive design](http://uxdesign.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/29/persuasion-triggers-in-web-design/), so called triggers which stimulate people to target behavior

Comment: Alexey, can you summarize the themes of the links you provided? The answers need to be complete in and of itself, rather than people being forced to follow a link to see what it is.

Answer (score 4):

**The more professional your site looks, the more trustworthy it is.** Think that typo doesn't matter? It does - just as typo's in spam are a red flag for users, it's the same for other interfaces. Keep the number of colors down - if your page looks like mid-90's Geocities, it's not going to encourage people to come.

**Keep the language measured and professional** - if someone is at the point of paying, they have already made a commitment to buy - focus on making payment easy.

**Consider the other pages**: If the rest of your site doesn't foster trust, it's unlikely anyone will get as far as paying. Consider where you can be objective - if a site is selling products and always recommending the most expensive, rather than what meets the users needs, it will quickly lose the trust of its users.

Answer (score 0):

While not the most important, colors do play into how a site is perceived. It is well noted that the color blue tends to invoke a bit more trust in a site.

A few links below as quick sources, a google search turns up alot more info:

http://improvetheweb.com/choosing-colors-for-your-design

http://www.aliciacowan.com/social-media-and-digital-marketing/strategy-and-advice/social-media-giants-branding

http://www.empower-yourself-with-color-psychology.com/color-blue.html